# Why does my await batch.execute() return undefined?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, web3-react

We want to get the n latest Blocks from ethereum mainnet. After initializing our web3 provider we need to acquire the block number of the latest block:

```
const latest = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
```

Based on `latest`'s number, we now define a [range](https://dev.to/ycmjason/how-to-create-range-in-javascript-539i) from `latest` to `latest - n - 1`. This will give the 5 latest blocknumbers:

```
const blockNumbers = range(latest - n, latest - 1);
```

No we batchrequest getBlock n times:

```
const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
  blockNumbers.forEach((blockNumber) => {
    batch.add(web3.eth.getBlock.request(blockNumber));
  })
```

We need an array for storing the return values:

```
let blocks = [];
```

Here comes the problem. Executing:

```
blocks = await batch.execute();
```

Returns one singular undefined. What am I doing wrong? I am fairly sure it's not the web3 provider, because

```
const latest = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
```

Returns valid numbers.

Here is the full code:

```
import web3 from "../ethereum/web3";

let blocks = [];
const range = (start, end, length = end - start + 1) =>
  Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => start + i)


export default async function getLatestBlocks(n) {
  console.log(`Get ${n} Blocks`)
  const latest = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
  const blockNumbers = range(latest - n, latest - 1);
  
  const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
  
  blockNumbers.forEach((blockNumber) => {
    batch.add(web3.eth.getBlock.request(blockNumber));
  })

  blocks = await batch.execute();
  console.log(blocks)
  return blocks;
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the current version `web3@^1` then the `execute` method returns indeed `void`. You should handle each response separately when adding the request to the batch:

```js
batch.add(web3.eth.getBlock.request(blockNumber), (err, block) => {
   // handle response, and check if all requests are completed.
});
```

This behavior we have implemented in [`dequanto`](https://github.com/0xweb-org/dequanto/blob/8443f596fb2bc14ee77fa7e9c4915fee35d4a827/src/clients/Web3BatchRequests.ts#L62) library